# Detect click on screen when in landscape

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout, android-scrollview

I'm having some trouble with detecting screen clicks on the GUI. Works in portrait but fails in landscape, see below.

I have a GUI (`Fragment`) which contains some instructions + images. The user is required to tap anywhere on the screen to proceed. In order capture the click/tap event, I have put in a `View`(topview) that fill the entire screen and sits onto of other elements, I then listen for clicks on this view and it works fine.

The problem is when in landscape mode, the text and images take up to much room. So the whole thing is now wrapped in a `ScrollView`. This is where the problem begins. When the `ScrollView` is active, (i.e. you can scroll/scroll bars are visible), my view on top (topview) disappears. It seems that when in landscape mode the height of content in a `ScrollView` is being changed. As an experiment I replaced the `View` with a `Button` and the `Button` goes from filling the screen in portrait to being normal height in landscape mode when the `ScrollView` is usable.

Is there a way of me detecting the user tapping on the screen, which works with the `ScrollView` control as the top element. I've tried rearranging the GUI in several ways but without success, and I've tried adding `onClick` event handlers to the `ScrollView`, also without success.

My Layout is below, note my top view is semi-transparent red, so I could see the area it covered.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:clickable="true" >

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtInstructions"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="@string/instructions"
            android:textColor="@color/blue"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:maxWidth="250dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/main_camera" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_to_listen_for_touch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:background="#88FF0000"
        android:clickable="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing that works(although looks like more like a hack(pretty ugly)) is to programatically add the special `View` in code(in the `onCreate` method) and set its dimensions based on the parent `RelativeLayout`'s exact dimensions. Here is a snippet of code:

```
//...
        final RelativeLayout parent = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ff);
        final View layer = new View(this);
        layer.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#88FF0000"));
        // the ScrollView really doesn't like this View ,using this without the
        // runnable will not work
        layer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        layer.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SDFD",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
        parent.addView(layer);
        // this is required because if we use directly the getWidth/getHeight we
        // will get 0/0
        layer.post(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                layer.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(parent
                        .getWidth(), parent.getHeight()));
            }
        });
//...
```

Comment: I've got no preference to having the scrollview as the top layout. I will try the code you suggested. I have tried it before, but maybe I did it wrong. When I last tried putting the view over the scrollview, in a frame layout it stopped the scrollview from scrolling.

Comment: Just tried your exact code. The scrollview cannot be scrolled when the view is on top of the scrollview. It needs to be inside of it.

Comment: @JonWillis Sorry about that, I totally forgot about the `ScrollView` when posting the answer. I've edited my answer and posted a solution that should work as I tested it but it's not that pretty.

Comment: why does getwidth/getheight return zero without posting it?

Comment: Confirmed that it works. Hacking it together in code was going to be my next attempt but thought I was overlooking something simple in the layouts. Thank you very much!

Comment: @JonWillis I'm glad I could help. The `post(Runnable)...` is required to delay getting the dimensions of the parent `RelativeLayout` because at that moment, in the `onCreate` method, the `Views`aren't laid out in the layout so their dimensions are `0`.

Comment: Thank you for coming back with an answer. That makes sense to me now. The onCreate is just preparing the view, as you say its not yet created. Again, many thanks.